# Who Added a SQL 2005 Login?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, login

I'm in the uncomfortable position of finding out one of my users has a db.owner level user account they are using.  We had previously taken away rights, but a whole new account was created to get around that.  A member of the IT staff has recently left, and I'm guessing he created it.

So, is it possible to see by whom (or even when) a SQL login was added in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT createdate,updatedate
FROM sys.sysusers
WHERE [name]='suspicious login'
```

Comment: Or a variation: SELECT * from master.dbo.syslogins where name = 'suspicious login'     Since all members of the sysadmin SQL Server role look alike, finding the miscreant will be difficult.  The fewer members of the sysadmin SQL Server role, the shorter the suspect list.  Happy hunting :-).

Comment: @jl Keep in mind that members of the securityadmin server role can also create server logins, not just members of sysadmin.

Comment: sys.sysusers is an old system table maintained only for backward compatability and should no longer be used.  sys.database_principals is its replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The Default Trace would have this information. [Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2005/64547/) is a good article on how to read the default trace.

Comment: Default Trace wasn't running.